# Proof of inequality : $\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}+\frac{1}{b^3+c^3+abc}+\frac{1}{c^3+a^3+abc}\le \frac{1}{abc}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Can we use AM-GM inequality proof method? I need a hint for proof.

Similar question: [To prove $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc} \le \frac{1}{abc}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261565/to-prove-sum-cyc-frac1a3b3abc-le-frac1abc)

If $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ and $a,b,c > 0$, then
$$
\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}+\frac{1}{b^3+c^3+abc}+\frac{1}{c^3+a^3+abc}\le \frac{1}{abc}
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261565/to-prove-sum-cyc-frac1a3b3abc-le-frac1abc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Can we use AM-GM? Which method was used in the other question?

Comment: So far all 3 posts of you have been problem-statement questions. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Again, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

By the rearrangement inequality, $a^3 + b^3 \geq a^2b + ab^2$. So we have
$$\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc} \leq \frac{1}{a^2b+ab^2+abc} = \frac{1}{ab(a+b+c)}.$$
The LHS is hence at most
$$\frac{1}{a+b+c} \left(\frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ac}\right),$$
and the result follows since
$$\frac{a+b+c}{abc} = \left(\frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ac}\right).$$