# How to obtain the maximum of this expression?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find the maximum of this expression $\frac{3}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{3}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{3}{c^3+a^3 + 3}$ , where $a,b,c $ are real numbers such that $abc = 3$.

What I have done is to use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to obtain:
$\left(\frac{1}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{c^3+a^3 + 3}\right) \left((a^3+b^3+3) + (b^3+c^3+3)+ (c^3+a^3 + 3)\right) \geq (1+1+1)^2 \geq 9$

Then we would have:

$\left(\frac{1}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{c^3+a^3 + 3}\right)\left(2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 9\right) \geq 9$

$\left(\frac{1}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{c^3+a^3 + 3}\right) \geq \frac{9}{2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 9}$

By AM-GM inequality we have:
$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3} $

$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq 3(abc) $

$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq 9 $

.

.

.

I have gotten $\left(\frac{1}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{1}{c^3+a^3 + 3}\right)\geq \frac{9}{2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 9} \leq \frac{1}{3}$

$\left(\frac{3}{a^3+b^3 + 3} + \frac{3}{b^3+c^3 + 3} + \frac{3}{c^3+a^3 + 3}\right)\geq \frac{27}{2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 9} \leq 1$

After this, I am unable to break flip the inequality sign and obtain $
\leq $ sign instead in order to obtain the maximum. Much help appreciated

Comment: Maybe one approach would be to have your first expression with the restriction of abc=5. [Extrema](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/AbsoluteExtrema.aspx) or [Lagrange Method]. Just make sure to have a bounded area and a,b,c>0 so that you can use the 3-d extrema theorem.

Comment: I doubt that the maximum exists. Juste take $a \to 0, b \to 0$ and $c = \frac{5}{ab}\to +\infty$ then the expression $P(a,b,c)$ converges to $1$ but there is no $(a,b,c)$ such that $P(a,b,c) = 1$

Comment: Just note: am-gm works for only non-negative real numbers.

Comment: all the numbers are positive. when a=b=c = sqrt(3), maximum is obtained but I am unable to flip the inequality sign

Comment: i made an edit to the post, abc is supposed to be 3

Comment: I think this link will help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261565/to-prove-sum-cyc-frac1a3b3abc-le-frac1abc